How to Scroll to a Specific Item Across Nested ListView Widgets in Flutter?
I'm working on a Flutter app where I have a nested ListView. The outer ListView displays a list of Surahs (chapters), and each Surah contains an inner ListView that displays a list of verses.
I need to implement a feature that allows scrolling directly to a specific verse in a specific Surah when the screen is loaded or when a button is pressed. I found that the scrollable_positioned_list package could help with this, but it seems to work only with single ListView  widgets (i.e., ScrollablePositionedList.builder). How to make it scroll directly to a specific verse (item in the inner List)?
Here's a simplified version of my code that I have tried:
class SurahDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int surahIndex;
  final int initialAyat;
  final List<Surah> surahs;

  const SurahDetailScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.surahIndex,
    this.initialAyat = 1,
    required this.surahs,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SurahDetailScreenState createState() => _SurahDetailScreenState();
}

class _SurahDetailScreenState extends State<SurahDetailScreen> {
  ItemScrollController _surahScrollController = ItemScrollController();
  ItemScrollController _verseScrollController = ItemScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      // Add logic to scroll to the specific verse after the build
      _surahScrollController.scrollTo(
        index: widget.surahIndex,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      );
      _verseScrollController.scrollTo(
        index: widget.initialAyat,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Surah Details'),
      ),
      body: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
        initialScrollIndex: widget.surahIndex,
        itemCount: widget.surahs.length,
        itemScrollController: _surahScrollController,
        itemBuilder: (context, surahIndex) {
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                widget.surahs[surahIndex].name,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              ),
              ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
                initialScrollIndex: widget.initialAyat,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemScrollController: _verseScrollController,
                itemCount: widget.surahs[surahIndex].verses.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, verseIndex) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('${widget.surahs[surahIndex].verses[verseIndex]}'),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}



